# Пропала графика при смене сервера. Почему?

Tags: apache, сервер, linux

Сменил сервер с Windows с модулем Apache 1.3 на Linux с модулем fast CGI. Пропало 30% графики. Причем непонятно, по какой системе. В каталогах все файлы на месте. Вопрос:

```
<td width="180" rowspan="2">
<img src="Image/logo1.jpg">
</td>
```

Такое поддерживается на Linux сервере?

Comment: Проверьте регистр разрешений картинок так же... после точки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NIX чувствителен к регистру символов, в отличие от windows. Так что проверьте имена папок и файлов, а так же ссылки на них в коде.

Comment: Проверил. Все нормально. Тогда еще вопрос. Папка начинается с заглавной буквы Image. В коде тоже заглавная. Может надо все с маленькими писать? Я всегда старался записывать правильно файлы и папки.

Comment: Да не, это уже по идее неважно. Главное чтоб и в коде и фактически было одинаково. А все изображения находятся в папке Image? и из нее же часть показывается, а часть нет?

Comment: я бы посоветовал и там и там писать с маленькой буквы но еще и проверить имена файлов и расширения. часто под виндой расширения файлов тоже бывают в верхнем регистре

Comment: Все проверил. Регистры все нормальные. Причем у меня есть и другие папки с заглавными буквами. Там тоже часть работает - часть не хочет.

Comment: ну ради интереса проверьте, переименуйте папку и ссылку на неотображаемый файл и приведите все к нижнему регистру и посмотрите будет ли после этого отображаться

Comment: и старайтесь всетаки пути указывать абсолютные /Image/logo1.jpg а не относительные как сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте права доступа для Апача (www-data) на те папки и файлы, где хранятся изображения.   Или в качестве эксперимента можно временно проставить 777 на все и посмотреть, появятся ли картинки.

Comment: ну это врятли поможет, т.к. из одной и той же папки часть файлов отображается, а часть нет

Comment: Я с сервером *nix никогда не работал. Где надо проставить права доступа?

Comment: Пример
chmod 777 images

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать

Comment: Всем спасибо...))) Все оказалось просто. Не отображались файлы с буквой L. Дело было в регистре...))) Не сразу это заметил.

Comment: а кто ответ принимать будет? ;)